# Question on convergence of sums of sequences.

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\{x_{j,n}\}_{j,n\in \mathbb N}\subset \mathbb R_+$ is such that for each $j$, $x_{j,n}\to x_j^*$ and  $\sum_j x_j^*<\infty$ Under what conditions does

$$\lim_n\sum_{j} x_{j,n}=\sum_j x_j^*$$
hold?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you want to check the monotone convergence and the dominated convergence theorems

Comment: Thanks I realized of the answer a couple of seconds after I wrote it. Nonetheless, maybe better to leave it in case someone else has the same question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the dominate convergence theorem if $x_{j,n}<\tilde x_j$ for every $n$ and  $\sum_j x_j<\infty$, then the limit holds true. A similar result can be obtained by using the monotone convergence theorem.